# System.Runtime not found when starting ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've published a Web App (using VS 2015).
When I run the .dll I get an error saying:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The sys
>   tem cannot find the file specified.
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decorat
>   edToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean&
>    isVarArg)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList de
>   rivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
>      at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
>      at System.AppDomain.GetTargetFrameworkName()

(This is odd, since it says that even on plain blank application...)

Here is the project.json file:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Modules": "1.0.0-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "config.json",
      "Views"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final" },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And the `Modules` project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0",
    "MailKit": "1.10.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone knows what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to run the dll using `dotnet run .dll` and not `./.dll`. The dotnet framework will do the rest for you.